# PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK not turning off screen

Tags: android

On button press, the following lines are executed. However, the screen is not turned off.

How to turn off screen?

```
    PowerManager.WakeLock screenLock = ((PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)).newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "turnOff");
    screenLock.acquire();
    screenLock.release();
```

I have also tried

```
DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
dpm.lockNow();
```

But it doesn't work as well because it requires admin.

Comment: The device will turn off the screen on its own, after a period of inactivity, and when no app holds a `WakeLock` other than `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`.

Comment: I want to turn the screen off on user command.

Comment: The user can press the power button to do that.

Comment: That is not what I'm asking.